# Operation cannot be unwrapped when deploying contract first webservice through CXF

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, cxf

I need to deploy a contract first web service. The service itself is very simple, just a ping operation to check if the system is available.

Ping.wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<definitions targetNamespace="urn:hl7-org:v3" name="Ping" xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:hl7-org:v3" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xsd:include schemaLocation="../schemas_codeGen/COMT_IN118118.xsd" />
            <xsd:include schemaLocation="../schemas_codeGen/COMT_IN229229.xsd" />
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>

    <message name="COMT_IN118118"><part name="body" element="hl7:COMT_IN118118" /></message>
    <message name="COMT_IN229229"><part name="body" element="hl7:COMT_IN229229" /></message>

    <portType name="Ping_PortType">
        <operation name="Ping_PingPong">
            <input message="hl7:COMT_IN118118" />
            <output message="hl7:COMT_IN229229" />
        </operation>
    </portType>

    <binding type="hl7:Ping_PortType" name="Ping_Binding">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <operation name="Ping_PingPong">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:hl7-org:v3/Ping_PingPong" />
            <input><soap:body use="literal" /></input>
            <output><soap:body use="literal" /></output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="Ping_Service">
        <port binding="hl7:Ping_Binding" name="Ping_Port"><soap:address location="http:/www.xis.nl/Ping" /></port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

I should be able to call this webservice on the remote as well as provide this service, so that the remote can call the service on my machine. I generated Java code from the WSDL with wsimport, resulting in Java classes for the COMT_IN118118 and COMT_IN229229 messages as well as an interface PingPortType with necessary annotations for deployment:

```
@WebService(name = "Ping_PortType", targetNamespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface PingPortType {
    @WebMethod(operationName = "Ping_PingPong", action = "urn:hl7-org:v3/Ping_PingPong")
    @WebResult(name = "COMT_IN229229", targetNamespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3", partName = "body")
    public COMTIN229229MCCIMT000300Message pingPingPong(
        @WebParam(name = "COMT_IN118118", targetNamespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3", partName = "body")
        COMTIN118118MCCIMT000100Message body);
}
```

I'd like to deploy my service through spring and added to my applicationContext:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="pingEndpoint" address="/Ping"
    implementor="com.application.services.impl.PingServiceImpl"
    wsdlLocation="wsdl/Ping.wsdl" serviceName="hl7:Ping_Service"
    endpointName="hl7:Ping_Port">
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

"hl7" here is short for the "urn:hl7-org:v3" namespace, PingServiceImpl is the class implementing PingPortType.

On startup, CXF logs:

```
Operation {urn:hl7-org:v3}Ping_PingPong cannot be unwrapped, input message must reference global element declaration with same localname as operation
```

Which is weird, as the @SoapBinding on PingPortType states that the parameterStyle should be BARE, instead of the default WRAPPED. Something is ignoring / overriding my @SoapBinding, but I can't figure out what.

Also, why would CXF log this as DEBUG message? In my opinion, ERROR would be much more appropriate (and appreciated...).

Comment: Hi, I have similar problem. Did you find a decision ?

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not. In my case, the problem had to do with conflicting web service frameworks. Combining Axis, Axis2 and CXF is not a good idea (big project, 30+ developers, lots of legacy code). We decided to rewrite all the old web service logic with CXF.